# Подсчет элементов в области

Tags: java, img

Имеется картинка: 
[тыц](http://d309jmebo4xh7g.cloudfront.net/tasks/09/io475550c431179121772b0f433c4a1a85d9dbe3d541e4.png)

Она состоит из черной сетки и черных точек на белом фоне. Нужно подсчитать количество точек. В какую сторону копать? В голове только мысль прохождения по пиксельной матрице картинки с анализом областей на предмет, является ли это точкой или нет. Проблема в том, что эта картинка кроме черно-белых пикселей содержит другие цвета. `rgb-список` показал около 16 цветов.

Answer (score 1):

1. перевести эти цвета на 2 цвета (grystolize)
2. пройти по пикселю.

еще можно взять среднее по квадрату размером больше пикселя. к примеру 10px на 10px и тогда изображение еще менше будет

Answer (score 1):

1. Почистить картинку (все что не черный - залить в белый)
2. Посчитать кол-во компонент связности поиском в ширину или глубину (достаточно проверять 4-х связность).

Если полоски сетки и после 1 шага будут связывать "точки", то их можно вычистить заметив, что у них примерно одинаковая ширина существенно меньше ширины "точек".